# Irrigation well under pressure, why is that?

Tags: well, irrigation

I am located in Florida. I have an irrigation well and when I open the valve for the pipe that is on the top of the well, the water is under pressure.

Pump is mounted on the side and is a surface mounted jet pump. Well is probably less than 25 FT deep.

Why am I seeing water under pressure from the well?

Comment: Where in Florida is the well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An [artesian well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artesian_well) brings water up to the surface without pumping. This is because the water in the underground reservoir is under pressure because it has water in the water-bearing layer at a higher altitude, and is not able to escape before you drill down into the layer. These are encountered in many areas of the world.

Comment: +1! You can self-delete your now duplicate comment on the OP. ;)